# embedding twitter timeline with count in angular 7

Tags: angular7

I have embedded twitter time line in angular 7 using

Problems: I got too many twitters and I want only one or two etc

```
     <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
     charset="utf-8"></script>
   <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" data-link- 
        color="#E95F28" 
                 [href]="twitter_link">
                      </a>   

     <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
     charset="utf-8"></script>
     <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" data-link- 
       color="#E95F28" 
                 href="https://twitter.com/ICICIBank? 
     ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
                      </a>
```

expected result should be: only one twitter time line not all blog
actual result is comming with all twitter time line

Answer (score 0):

try this. just put data-tweet="3",. here 3 in count

```
     <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" data-link-color="#E95F28" 
        [href]="company?.companyIdentityNumber + '?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'"
          data-tweet-limit="2">
```